# Caliburn The dependency property target is invalid

Tags: uwp, caliburn.micro, uwp-xaml

I'm getting this annoying message in my XAML files:

[image]

---

[image]

---

[image]

---

Anyone knows how to fix it?

*Visual Studio 2015 and 2017*
*Resharper*

---

**Edit:**

> **My conclusion is that the framework doesn't contribute to this errors, it is a VS BUG or something else because it happens with
>   different types of MVVM frameworks.**

Comment: There is a similar issue, please refer it in [https://github.com/Caliburn-Micro/Caliburn.Micro/issues/381](https://github.com/Caliburn-Micro/Caliburn.Micro/issues/381).

Comment: Yep,  that's me on that post, I thought that the problem was solved. Any tag that refers to Caliburn this message appears. @Scavenger

Answer (score 1):

It's not a fix but might be something to consider using instead of the `micro:Message.Attach`. Can you try using Behaviours instead

```
  <ListView IsItemClickEnabled="True"...>
    <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
      <core:EventTriggerBehavior EventName="ItemClick">
        <core:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding ItemClick}" />
      </core:EventTriggerBehavior>
    </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
  </ListView>
```

You can then bind to a `ICommand` in your ViewModel. You can find an example of creating a `CommandHandler` [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/da35a791-a179-4859-a445-a29d74bdc2db/uwphow-do-i-bind-a-ui-event-to-a-method-in-a-viewmodel-class-in-xaml?forum=wpdevelop).

Comment: The capability of 'Avoid' `ICommand` It's a cool feature, I don't want to miss it. Thanks anyway